# Radio Button overlapping the Coressponding text

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

[image: Snapshot of the two radio buttons used]

The **radio buttons** are **overlapping** the text value of them. Also it isnt taking the entire screen , i tried controlgroup asd well . What is the issue in this?
I am using **jquery-1.10.min.js** and **jquery-mobile-1.4.0.min.js** and following is the code snippet

```
    <div data-role="content">
    <form>
        <div class="ui-grid-b ">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    <input type="radio" name="income" value="Monthly">Monthly</input>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    <input type="radio" name="income" value="Annually">Annually</input>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I replaced yor code with the below code and its working fine.And the main reason for your misalignment is because of the jquery mobile inline style.In jqm, add an input with a type="radio" attribute and a corresponding label and  set the for attribute of the label to match the id of the input so they are semantically associated.

```
<div class="ui-grid-b ">
          <div class="ui-block-a">
              <input type="radio" name="income" value="Monthly" id="radio-choice-2"/>
              <label for="radio-choice-2">Monthly</label>
          </div>
```

Demo :http://plnkr.co/edit/beYWdwSmtzYCaRS4ibYK?p=preview

I hope you find it useful